# Bokeh charts with multiple font sizes in LabelSets

Tags: python, bokeh

community,

I am building a TreeMap using squarify + bokeh. I would like to have different text_font_sizes for each label as the bigger squares have a lot of space for a small font and the small squares sometimes are not big enough for a medium font.

I already tried doing the following (I have 10 items in the chart):

```
plotsource = ColumnDataSource(
    data=dict(
        Xlab = Xlab,
        Ylab = Ylab,

        Share = Share,
        Colors = source.data['Colors'],
        LabelColors = source.data['LabelColors'],
        Labels = source.data['Labels'],
        FontSizes = ['10pt']*10,

    )
)

…

labels1 = LabelSet(x='Xlab', y='Ylab', text='Labels', level='glyph',
    text_font_style='bold', text_color='LabelColors', text_align = 'center', source=plotsource, text_font_size='FontSizes')
```

if I use `text_font_size='10pt'` it works just fine, but with the array it doesn’t. I just used the same size for every element in the array to show that it does not work with an array.

Any clues on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an array for `text_font_size` is indeed not possible. I've added an ugly workaround to my answer. You could create a feature request on the [Github page](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/new?assignees=&labels=TRIAGE&template=feature_request.md&title=%5BFEATURE%5D) if you want it to be added.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Range1d, LabelSet, Label

output_file("label.html", title="label.py example")

plotsource = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(Xlab=[66, 71, 72, 68, 58, 62],
                                    Ylab=[165, 189, 220, 141, 260, 174],
                                    Labels=['Mark', 'Amir', 'Matt', 'Greg', 'Owen', 'Juan'],
                                    LabelColors=['red', 'green', 'blue', 'purple', 'gold', 'pink'],
                                    FontSizes=['12pt', '14pt', '16pt', '18pt', '20pt', '22pt']))

p = figure(title='Dist. of 10th Grade Students at Lee High')
p.scatter(x='Xlab', y='Ylab', size=8, source=plotsource)
p.xaxis[0].axis_label = 'Weight (lbs)'
p.yaxis[0].axis_label = 'Height (in)'

labels1 = []

for x, y, label, color, fontsize in zip(plotsource.data['Xlab'], plotsource.data['Ylab'], plotsource.data['Labels'], plotsource.data['LabelColors'], plotsource.data['FontSizes']):
    labels1.append(Label(x=x, y=y, text=label, level='glyph', text_font_style='bold', text_color=color, text_align ='center', text_font_size=fontsize))
    p.add_layout(labels1[-1])

show(p)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Jasper! It is a good workaround. =) I was thinking of doing so but I would like to see if there was something I was missing...